# Remove multiple slashes but preserve trailing one

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rule in my .htaccess to remove multiple trailing slashes. It works:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ (.*)//([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ %2/%3 [R=301,L]
```

I also have a rule that adds one trailing slash if it's missing. On its own, it works, too:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is pretty obvious - remove multiple slashes, leave one. But with first rule applied, I'm getting no trailing slash on **index page** even when I specify it.
Please help me to combine these rules into one or at least get them to work properly. I tried to use [this tool](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) for debug but it is unable to process %{THE_REQUEST}.

I'll leave rest of .htaccess file for the reference, maybe it interferes. It wasn't written my be but I have to figure it out.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^styles
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^uss-js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^uss-css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^uss-img
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^uploadedFiles
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.ico|\.ICO)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.jpg|\.JPG)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.jpeg|\.JPEG)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.png|\.PNG)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.gif|\.GIF)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.CSS)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.js|\.JS)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?reference=$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.ico|\.ICO)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.jpg|\.JPG)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.jpeg|\.JPEG)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.png|\.PNG)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.gif|\.GIF)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.css|\.CSS)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.js|\.JS)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ [R=404]
```

Comment: Something else is going on because these rules work just fine for me/

Comment: Thanks for your time. I put rest of .htaccess in the question, maybe problem is there.

Comment: You sure index.php isn't doing any kind of redirecting? Also, your last rule will never work. THere's no way a request can end with both `.ico` and `.jpg`.

Comment: Thanks, I will fix it. There's no redirecting in index.php afaik, any suggestions what to look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm getting no trailing slash on index page

Yes you won't because your trailing slash adding rule has this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Which means if request is for a valid file then don't execute.

You can add a trailing slash in your first rule also:

```
# remove multiple slashes from URL and add a trailing one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1/ [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks! I starting to understanf it. I changed my .htaccess accordingly, but still, problem is present - no trailing slash on index page, I'm getting `http://myurl.com` instead of `http://myurl.com/`.

Comment: You're mistaken here. You cannot add a trailing slash just after domain name with no URL. Take example of `https://www.google.co.uk/` It becomes `https://www.google.co.uk`

Comment: Thanks! Turns out, I was wrong =) I was able to finish the task thanks to your answer, wish I was able to upvote.

Comment: No issues, glad it helped. btw you have 15+ rep now :)